# Azure App Insights - Add Custom Property to Dependency Calls

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an app service (.NET 4.6.2) which sends custom telemetry Trace entries to App Insights.  These Trace entries contain custom properties which help us filter the log to specific ID's.

However, when filtering the App Insights log by ID, we lose visibility to Dependency calls since the Dependency call does not contain the same custom property as the Trace.

Is there a way to add custom properties to Dependency calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TelemetryInitializers is the correct way of adding any additional custom property to **any** telemetry type  - Traces/Dependencies/Requests etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer

Also if you are using default config, Dependencies/Traces made within the context of a Request will be automatically correlated together for you with same 'operation_id'.

Comment: Thanks @cijothomas.  I suddenly got much busier and have not had time to go back and try this out, but I will for sure soon and mark as answer when done.

Comment: There is a (smart) way to add custom property to a specific Dependencies? I have a HttpClient request to track, but I want to put a custom property for this call.